# How to update GDB to most current, stable version

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, updates, package-managers, apt

I am using gdb version 6.8 on an ubuntu 9 machine image. I would like to update it to the latest one (7.8?) but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried following the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/529781/upgrade-from-gdb-7-7-to-7-8 but they didn't work.

It stopped at the tar command and said "this does not look a tar file"

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it might be the case that your version of `tar` is so old it does not support the xz compression scheme.  The link you reference suggests downloading `gdb-7.8.tar.xz`, you can try running `unxz gdb-7.8.tar.xz` which will uncompress the file into `gdb-7.8.tar`, you can then retry `tar -xf gdb-7.8.tar` which should now work.

Alternatively you could try downloading this file instead `http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.8.2.tar.gz`, this is the 7.8.2 release compared to the 7.8 you were using before, and so contains a few minor bug fixes, however, this file uses the gzip compression scheme, which has been supported in tar for longer than xz, this new file should extract fine with `tar -xf gdb-7.8.2.tar.gz`.

Finally, you might be interested in skipping 7.8 completely, and moving straight to 7.10 (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.10.tar.gz) as this should contain even more exciting new features and improvements.

Answer (score 10):

Updating GDB from 7.7.1 to 8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install gdb
gdb -v
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: 'Didn't work for me on `Ubuntu 20.04`. Latest is currently 11.1, but I seem stuck at the (buggy) 10.2.

Answer (score 8):

You can also build and install GDB yourself from [the official source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/).  However be aware that there are some quirks to this process on Ubuntu 20 LTS.  If you dynamically link the C++ libs then you'll possibly get errors running GDB.  One solution is to statically link.  This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (aka focal) x86_64 with GDB 10.2.  These instructions assume you have downloaded gdb-10.2.tar.gz (or whatever version you wish to build) and moved it into your home directory.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential texinfo
cd
tar -xvzf gdb-10.2.tar.gz
cd gdb-10.2
./configure
make CXXFLAGS="-static-libstdc++"
sudo make install
gdb --version
```

**NOTE >>** If you notice **python errors** when running gdb --version then a reboot will fix this and perhaps even just logging off and logging back in.

Comment: Your solution actually works. I installed GDB 11.1. Also, log off and log in back are also needed too.

Comment: I just have to restart my terminal to get the new version installed without the Python error.