# Message "test test_gdb failed" while installing Python-3.5.1 on Linux

Tags: python, testing

While installing Python-3.5.1 on Linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS, after running command:

```
make test
```

I got a message:

```
test test_gdb failed
```

I've made a single test with command:

```
./python -m test -v test_gdp
```

and I got this:

```
== CPython 3.5.1 (default, Dec 10 2015, 00:27:11) [GCC 4.8.4]
==   Linux-3.19.0-25-generic-i686-athlon-with-debian-jessie-sid little-endian
==   hash algorithm: siphash24 32bit
==   /Desktop/Python-3.5.1/build/test_python_11095
Testing with flags: sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0)
[1/1] test_gdp
test test_gdp crashed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/Python-3.5.1/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 1292, in runtest_inner
the_module = importlib.import_module(abstest)
  File "/Desktop/Python-3.5.1/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'test.test_gdp'

1 test failed:
    test_gdp
```

I have gdp installed.

How to fix it? 
Or can I just ignore it?

Comment: `test_gdb` or `test_gdp`? The second one fails, because you mistyped `gdp` instead of `gdb`: the error says so: "No module named 'test.test_gdp'". Gdp doesn't exist because of your typo.

Comment: Try running `gdb` or `gdb --version` by itself. That should give you more information on what's wrong. Add that to your question.

Comment: It looks like there was a typo in the tutorial/documentation that I used to copy the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Python 3.8.3 on my system.

My system was running gdb version :

```
~/Downloads/Python-3.8.3$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

with my Ubuntu version being `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

A simple [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239291) to the `gdb` package **fixed it** for me.

New `gdb` version :

```
$ gdb -v
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1~18.04) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Then running `make test` resulted in **success**:

```
~/Downloads/Python-3.8.3$ make test
 CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared    ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall'  _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS=''   ./python -E ./setup.py  build
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_dbm                  _lzma                 _tkinter           
_uuid                                                          
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
_abc                  atexit                pwd                
time                                                           

running build_scripts
copying and adjusting /home/qbuser/Downloads/Python-3.8.3/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.8
copying and adjusting /home/qbuser/Downloads/Python-3.8.3/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.8
copying and adjusting /home/qbuser/Downloads/Python-3.8.3/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.8
changing mode of build/scripts-3.8/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.8/idle3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.8/2to3 from 644 to 755
renaming build/scripts-3.8/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.8/pydoc3.8
renaming build/scripts-3.8/idle3 to build/scripts-3.8/idle3.8
renaming build/scripts-3.8/2to3 to build/scripts-3.8/2to3-3.8
./python  ./Tools/scripts/run_tests.py 
/home/qbuser/Downloads/Python-3.8.3/python -u -W default -bb -E -m test -r -w -j 0 -u all,-largefile,-audio,-gui
== CPython 3.8.3 (default, Jun 18 2020, 21:02:16) [GCC 7.5.0]
== Linux-5.3.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27 little-endian
== cwd: /home/qbuser/Downloads/Python-3.8.3/build/test_python_15689
== CPU count: 8
== encodings: locale=UTF-8, FS=utf-8
Using random seed 8229413
0:00:00 load avg: 0.39 Run tests in parallel using 10 child processes
0:00:00 load avg: 0.39 [  1/423] test_bool passed
0:00:00 load avg: 0.39 [  2/423] test_osx_env passed
.
.
.
.
0:02:25 load avg: 4.58 [420/423] test_tokenize passed (35.3 sec) -- running: test_multiprocessing_forkserver (40.5 sec), test_multiprocessing_spawn (1 min 5 sec), test_concurrent_futures (42.0 sec)
0:02:55 load avg: 3.21 running: test_multiprocessing_forkserver (1 min 10 sec), test_multiprocessing_spawn (1 min 35 sec), test_concurrent_futures (1 min 12 sec)
0:02:56 load avg: 3.21 [421/423] test_multiprocessing_spawn passed (1 min 36 sec) -- running: test_multiprocessing_forkserver (1 min 11 sec), test_concurrent_futures (1 min 12 sec)
0:02:57 load avg: 3.21 [422/423] test_multiprocessing_forkserver passed (1 min 11 sec) -- running: test_concurrent_futures (1 min 13 sec)
0:03:27 load avg: 2.08 running: test_concurrent_futures (1 min 43 sec)
0:03:57 load avg: 1.32 running: test_concurrent_futures (2 min 13 sec)
0:04:05 load avg: 1.34 [423/423] test_concurrent_futures passed (2 min 21 sec)

== Tests result: SUCCESS ==

404 tests OK.

19 tests skipped:
    test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll test_idle test_ioctl test_kqueue
    test_lzma test_msilib test_ossaudiodev test_startfile test_tcl
    test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_ttk_textonly test_turtle
    test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64

Total duration: 4 min 5 sec
Tests result: SUCCESS
```